# Minor query about windows authentication using C# and custom roles

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-authentication

I have visual studio installed on my local machine and the MVC project is present for the development server. 
I have to use windows authentication to see if users are authenticated using windows login.

All users will have a local workstation of the company and they are going to login to the website we are developing using visual studio and development server.

My query is- if i do windows authentication, i need to check the windows user details of the employee in the companys user database. I donot want to check the active directory of the development server where the website is present.

Will this code help me to check authentication by referring it to the companys active directory database ?

```
if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that works regardless of what kind of authentication you are using.  However, you want

```
HttpContext...
```

not

```
httpContext
```

Also, you'll need to enable windows authentication in your web.config file for this to work.

```
<system.web>
  ...
   <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  ...
</system.web>
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Comment: web.config file changes means i am changing the configuration at the server side. i dont want to use server side authentication. instead i am looking to check if user is having company credentials. i.e. the login credentials which an employee uses for work.

Comment: no.  web.config change enables the web server to use "passthrough authentication"  You'll never get authenticated using windows without it.  I'll post the fragment you want next.

Comment: The link is valid for ASP.NET 2.0. Will the steps be the same for ASP.NET 5.0 ?

Comment: Yes, not much as changed with authentication since 1.0 other than adding other providers.

If it makes you any more comfortable, I just did this on a project two months ago.